# Choosing an equal number of samples from each strata - what is this called?

Tags: sampling, bias, stratification

Suppose I have a highly skewed distribution and a proxy measurement. I use this proxy measurement to bin the samples of this distribution into different "strata". I then take N samples from each strata (therefore I take samples from each strata with equal probability). What is this approach called? It doesn't appear to fit under the two types of stratified sampling mentioned in the wiki article: proportionate and optimal allocation.

Is there an implementation of this approach in python or some other language/package? I ask because while this is a simple thing to implement there may be some strata that don't have enough samples and others with many more samples than N (in which case I might have to perform several iterations or sample without replacement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a type of "disproportional sampling". In particular it would be "equal allocation".

I've never tried it, but from this Stack Overflow question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606447/sampling-from-a-large-dataset, it appears that [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) in `pandas` should be able to perform the sampling, although it might not work if the sample size is larger than the number of elements in a strata. Perhaps some other answers on Stack Overflow could help with that.